# ListDensityPlot3D with thick points or BarLegend for Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, legending

I have a small number of points in 3D space. Each point has an associated weight (real number). For each point, I want to plot a [visible point] whose color is a function of the weight value.

It seems like `ListDensityPlot3D` would work for this, but I just get a blank space and I think this is because the points are spaced so far apart and I cannot find an `PointSize` option for `ListDensityPlot3D`.

My closest work around is to use `Graphics3D` and `Point`, but I cannot use a `BarLegend` because "BarLegend is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive".

I have pasted my workaround and my attempt at using `ListDensityPlot3D`.

```
x = {0, -0.1, 0};
y = {0, 0.8, 0};
z = {0, -0.5, 1};
T = {90.9, 57.7, 0};

Graphics3D[{
  Table[
   {Hue[T[[i]]], PointSize[0.03],
    Point[
     {x[[i]], y[[i]], z[[i]]}
     ]},
   {i, 1, 3}],
  Opacity[0.05], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]},
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1
 ]

ListDensityPlot3D[
 Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]], z[[i]], T[[i]]}, {i, 1, 3}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BubbleChart3D[Thread[{x, y, z, 1}], 
 BubbleSizes -> Medium, 
 Boxed -> True,
 ChartStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[T]), 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[T, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"],
 FaceGrids -> {}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 List /@ Transpose[{x, y, z}],
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green},
 PlotLegends -> T
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `PlotLegends -> T` would be more descriptive.

Comment: @BobHanlon Updated.